# Is the convolution of a tempered distribution and a Schwartz function also a function?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution, schwartz-space

Let $T \in \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $f \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. We may define their convolution as
$$(T * f)(\varphi) = T(\tilde{f}*\varphi)$$
where $\tilde{f}(x) = f(-x)$. The above convolution is defined to be a tempered distribution, that is $(T * f) \in \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In Reed and Simon (Volume II, Theorem IX.4), they say

> $T*f$ is a polynomially bounded $C^\infty$ function, i.e. $T * f \in O_M^n$. In fact, $(T * f)(y) = T(\tilde{f}_y)$ and $$D^\beta(T * f) = (D^\beta T) * f = T * D^\beta f.$$

Here $\tilde{f}_y$ is the function $f(y-x)$.

I am confused as I thought $(T*f)$ is a distribution, but in the above passage they are treating it as a Schwartz function by applying it to $y$ and bounding it by a polynomial. How would this make sense for a distribution?

Comment: It is a-priori a distribution, but the claim is that it is represented by an at-most polynomially increasing function, and that furthermore the value of that function at $y$ equals the value of the distribution $T$ on that translated function $\tilde{f}_y$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, by a representation do you mean there is a $C^\infty$ bounded function $g$ such that $\langle g, \phi\rangle = \langle (T * f), \phi\rangle$ for all Schwartz functions $\phi$?

Comment: Well it may not be bounded, but yes that’s what “represented by a function” means (where the LHS means the integral of $g\phi$). The function $g$ could be unbounded, but the worst is polynomial growth, rather than say exponential.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for your help!